# Selectivity of Zinin Reduction

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, amines, nitro-compounds

What is it, that makes the Zinin Reduction a selective reduction, and not a complete reduction, in the case of dinitrobenzenes? Also, is the reaction a selective one even when it is done for aliphatic dinitro compounds, or is it, in that case,  a complete reduction to diamine? What about polynitro-aromatic compounds?

Do the relative positions of the two nitro groups in dinitrobenzene affect the reaction and its selectivity?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/selective-nitro-reduction-of-poly-nitro-compounds/53698#53698

Comment: To whomever keeps flagging the comment, the question cited is *related* to this one, the commenter is not purporting that this question is a duplicate of that one or that the linked question answers this one completely.