# Zinin Reduction of 1,3-dinitrobenzene

Tags: synthesis

Remember asking my chemistry teacher this question in 1979/80: in the reduction of 1,3-dinitrobenzene with hydrogen sulphide/ aqueous ammonia, why is only one nitro group reduced?. He said that the reaction must be driven by the electon-depleted ring (two nitro groups); as one nitro-group becomes an amino, electron density in the ring increases, by definition; therefore, the reaction stops.

This is almost certainly true; but, is there a more fulsome explanation? Attempts to find the mechanism, on the net, have established that it has not yet been elucidated.

Any thoughts; theories; ideas; or, is this a worthy Ph.D. project for an ambitious young student?

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/selective-nitro-reduction-of-poly-nitro-compounds/53698#53698

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68817/selectivity-of-zinin-reduction