# Reduction of nitro group to amine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

[image]

In the above reaction, I do know that $\ce{SnCl2/HCl}$ reduces $\ce{-NO2}$ group to $\ce{-NH2}$ but which one of the two $\ce{-NO2}$ will be reduced first by $\ce{SnCl2/HCl}$? Why so?

And how does $\ce{NH4HS}$ react and again which one of the two $\ce{-NO2}$ will be reduced first by $\ce{NH4HS}$ and why so?

**NOTE**: 1eq represents 1 equivalent.

Comment: Partial duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/selective-nitro-reduction-of-poly-nitro-compounds/53698#53698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hyperconjugation accounts for the somewhat greater negativity of the 4-nitro-group compared with the 2-nitro-group in 2:4-dinitrotoluene; in consequence, selective reduction of the former by alkaline sulphides produces mainly 2-nitro-4-aminotoluene, although some 4-nitro-2-aminotoluene is also formed. In acid medium the 2-nitro-group becomes relatively negative in comparison with the 4-nitro-group, owing to the inductive (+I) effect having the chief role, with resultant preferential salt formation to give the very positive $\ce{-NO2H}$ group at 2-position and preferential reduction of it by acid stannous chloride.

Quoted from Coloration Technology **62** (1946) 114

As for how ammonium sulphide reacts see this answer:  [Selective nitro reduction of poly nitro compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/selective-nitro-reduction-of-poly-nitro-compounds/53698#53698)