# Preparation of m-nitroaniline from m-dinitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, amines, nitro-compounds

Consulting various Organic Chemistry resources, I have found two reactions for the purpose stated in the subject:

First reaction:

[image]

Second  reaction:
[image]

But, I cannot find the reaction mechanism by which they take place. Which would be necessary for an exercise, the conversion of m-dinitrobenzene to m-chloronitrobenzene, in which I want to introduce as an intermediate step one of these two reactions. I suppose that the mechanism will be very similar, but I cannot find what it is.

Comment: This is known as Zinin reduction, a review is here (if you have institutional access) :   https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/0471264180.or020.04  otherwise look here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/selective-nitro-reduction-of-poly-nitro-compounds  AFAIK the mechanism for this reaction remains obscure.

Comment: It does work. Have successfully reduced 4-methyl-3,5-dinitrobenzoic acid by the Zinin method.

Comment: I have also used this to selectively reduce dinitrobenzenes